# How to check if a function has been called in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I have a function as follows

```
pub fn registration(student_id: &T::StudentId, registrar: &T::RegistrarID) {
    // More code here.
    if num_of_students < student_limit {
        Self::function_one(&registrar, &num_of_students);
    } else {
        Self::function_two(&num_of_students);
    }
}
```

In unit tests, I am planning to check whether `function_one` or `function_two` was called.

```
#[test]
fn registration_more_students_should_call_functon_one() {
    with_test_data(
        &mut TestBuilder::default().num_of_students(1000).build(),
        || {
            //assert_called!(module_name::registration("TV:009", "DF-000-09"));
        },
    );
}
```

How can I test if a function was called in Rust?

Comment: I guess that your functions have a side effect, you can check this effect.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what it is or what it does, but the project name looks somewhat promising: [mock_derive](https://github.com/DavidDeSimone/mock_derive).

Comment: Follow-up of https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-how-to-check-whether-a-function-being-called-or-not/25045

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a naïve attempt using `#[cfg(test)]` in multiple places:

```
struct Registration {
    students: Vec<String>,
    #[cfg(test)]
    function_1_called: bool,
}

impl Registration {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Registration {
            students: Vec::new(),
            #[cfg(test)]
            function_1_called: false,
        }
    }

    fn function_1(&mut self, students: Vec<String>) {
        self.students.extend(students);
        #[cfg(test)]
        {
            self.function_1_called = true;
        }
    }

    fn function_2(&mut self, students: Vec<String>) {}

    fn f(&mut self, students: Vec<String>) {
        if students.len() < 100 {
            self.function_1(students);
        } else {
            self.function_2(students);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let r = Registration::new();
    // won't compile during `run`:
    // println!("{}", r.function_1_called);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_f() {
        let mut r = Registration::new();
        r.function_1(vec!["Alice".to_string(), "Bob".to_string()]);
        assert!(r.function_1_called);
    }
}
```

The code is loosely based on the snippets that you provided. There is a `Registration` struct that holds a list of student names, two methods `function_1` and `function_2` for registering students, and a function `f` that chooses between `function_1` and `function_2` depending o how many students there are.

During tests, `Registration` is compiled with an additional Boolean variable `function_1_called`. This variable is set only if `function_1` is called (the block of code that does that is also marked with `#[cfg(test)]`).

In combination, this makes an additional Boolean flag available during the tests, so that you can make assertions like the following one:

```
assert!(r.function_1_called);
```

Obviously, this could work for structures much more complicated than a single boolean flag (which does not at all mean that you should actually do it).

I cannot comment on whether this is idiomatic in Rust or not. The whole setup feels as if it should be hidden behind fancy macros, so if this style of testing is used in Rust at all, there should already be crates that provide those (or similar) macros.

Answer (score 11):

Strong opinion alert: *you are doing your testing wrong*. This is on the same level as "how do I test a private method". You shouldn't care about the implementation of `registration` to this level of detail.

That being said, if it's actually important to know which `if` branch is taken, then use dependency injection:

```
fn registration(mut registration: impl Registration, registrar: i32) {
    let num_of_students = 0;
    let student_limit = 0;

    if num_of_students < student_limit {
        registration.function_one(registrar, num_of_students);
    } else {
        registration.function_two(num_of_students);
    }
}

trait Registration {
    fn function_one(&mut self, registrar: i32, num_of_students: i32);
    fn function_two(&mut self, num_of_students: i32);
}

impl<R: Registration> Registration for &'_ mut R {
    fn function_one(&mut self, registrar: i32, num_of_students: i32) {
        (**self).function_one(registrar, num_of_students)
    }
    fn function_two(&mut self, num_of_students: i32) {
        (**self).function_two(num_of_students)
    }
}

/*
// An example implementation for production
struct DatabaseRegistration;

impl Registration for DatabaseRegistration {
    fn function_one(&mut self, registrar: i32, num_of_students: i32) {
        eprintln!("Do DB work: {}, {}", registrar, num_of_students)
    }
    fn function_two(&mut self, num_of_students: i32) {
        eprintln!("Do DB work: {}", num_of_students)
    }
}
*/

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;

    #[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, Default)]
    struct TestRegistration {
        calls_to_one: usize,
        calls_to_two: usize,
    }

    impl Registration for TestRegistration {
        fn function_one(&mut self, _: i32, _: i32) {
            self.calls_to_one += 1;
        }
        fn function_two(&mut self, _: i32) {
            self.calls_to_two += 1;
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn calls_the_right_one() {
        let mut reg = TestRegistration::default();
        registration(&mut reg, 42);
        assert_eq!(1, reg.calls_to_two)
    }
}
```

Once you have done this, then you can see that `registration` calls the appropriate trait function (as shown in the example test).

This prevents your production code from having test-specific detritus strewn about while also giving you the ability to be more flexible and test more cases rapidly.

See also:

- [How can I test stdin and stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28370126/155423)
- [How to mock external dependencies in tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51919079/155423)
- [Is there a cleaner way to test functions that use functions that require user input in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47077925/155423)
- [How can I test Rust methods that depend on environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35858323/155423)
- [Is there a way of detecting whether code is being called from tests in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50888225/155423)

Comment: I guess your opinion depends on the language you are most familiar with, unit tests should test the functionality not the other functions , Intention here was to test whether other function being called from the method

Comment: @Kalanamith Since you are not simply testing the external behavior of your function (comparing the return result), but you also want to see whether a certain other method is invoked, you are essentially testing the side effects (because the method invocation by itself is a sort of "side-effect", albeit a rather strange one). The usual practice when dealing with any kind of side-effects in tests would be to make the function *generic over an interpreter that performs the side effects*, and then to *inject* a special test-interpreter during the tests.

Comment: @Kalanamith In this sense, what Shepmaster proposed here is much closer to what I would usually do when writing my Scala code (this approach seems increasingly language agnostic, and applicable in many different ecosystems). I tried the `cfg`-approach mostly because I was curious whether it would compile at all, not because I would suggest it as a best practice.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yep, Agree.

Comment: This bit `impl<R: Registration> Registration for &'_ mut R` looks a bit like black magic. Can you add a little on why its needed and what it does?

Comment: Also - Can you avoid the need for changing `&self` to `&mut self` in the signature by using a RefCell for interior mutablity?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson yes, interior mutability is a good and common solution when your test implementations need mutability but your real code does/can not. That implementation is just [implementing the trait for all references to types that implement the trait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/155423). That's what allows us to pass in `&mut reg` in the test while holding onto our own copy. You could also use something like an `Rc` / `Arc` to keep a shared reference (and then you *need* to use interior mutability).

Comment: @Shepmaster In the accepted answer to the last question you linked, it is said: *"For this reason, taking the parameter to `runner()` by value is probably undesirable; you should instead be taking it by reference."* Wouldn't it also apply here if `mut registration: impl Trait` is replaced by `registration: &mut impl Trait`? Looks as if it could simplify the example a little bit.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin you are right that it would simplify this example, but I'd say that's largely because there's only the test code to look at. In a bigger example, you'd want to prioritize the production code. Maybe you'd want the `R` to be owned by the struct containing the method `registration` so that it can be returned from a function that created `R`. See the semi-related [API guideline about taking `Read` / `Write` by value](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#generic-readerwriter-functions-take-r-read-and-w-write-by-value-c-rw-value).