# Verify that method was called the expected number of times with correct parameters

Tags: rust

### Summary

I have an application that starts another process and transfers its StdOut/StdErr to a log file using the `log` crate. My application transfers the output line by line (`buf_read.read_line()`). As it can be any arbitrary process, my application makes the assumption that the other process may be malicious and may try to print to stdout/sterr enormous amounts of data without a single newline, thus causing OOM in my application. Hence my application limits the number of bytes the `BufReader` can read at a time using `BufReader.take()`.

### The problem

Ignoring all the details about chunking the input, how can I test that my logger was called X times with the correct parameters ? Let's assume my app has read one huge line and has split it in 3 parts like the MCVE below.

### MCVE:

```
use std::thread::JoinHandle;

fn main() {
    let handle = start_transfer_thread(&|x| {
        println!("X={}", x);
    }).join();
}

fn start_transfer_thread<F>(logger: &'static F) -> JoinHandle<()> where F: Send + Sync + Fn(&str) -> () {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        logger("1");
        logger("2");
        logger("3");
    })
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_logged_in_order() {
        let result = start_transfer_thread(&|x| {
            match x {
                "1" => (),
                "2" => (),
                "3" => (),
                x => panic!("unexpected token: {}", x)
            }
        }).join();
        assert!(result.is_ok());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just test your code with some long input and check the result ???!!!

Comment: I did that and I know that it works, but I want to have an automated test. Testing by hand is not an option.

Comment: You can get the logger from a trait object and Inject it as mock logger which implements the same trait. In your mock logger, you can add your desired logic and get the call count from it.

Comment: What you're describing is called a Spy. https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html

Comment: I know what a `spy` is, the question was how to do it with plain rust. In the end I replaced the function/closure with a trait object. Now in the tests I'm able to pass another implementation that accumulates the values using a channel. But still I have no idea how to do it if was a function/closure as in my MCVE.

Comment: @Kraylog, I was just describing the blog :) Could not wanted to just call it spy, instead wanted to give insight about implementation

Comment: @Shepmaster The linked duplicate does not answer the question. It makes the assumption that the function belongs to a struct which can conditionally contain the test state. My function is not associated with a struct, hence I cannot conditionally add a new field to the struct. As I had control over the whole codebase  I easily changed it to use a trait instead of function reference, but that might not have been possible if I was not in control of the API.

Comment: I don’t understand how you answer differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584732/155423).  Both use traits to solve the problem (although you chose to use dynamic dispatch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by replacing the function/closure with a trait object:

```
trait Logger: Send + Sync {
    fn log(&mut self, log_name: &str, data: &str);
}

struct StandardLogger;

impl Logger for StandardLogger {
    fn log(&mut self, log_name: &str, data: &str) {
        log::logger().log(
            &log::Record::builder()
                .level(log::Level::Info)
                .target(log_name)
                .args(format_args!("{}", data))
                .build(),
        );
    }
}
```

For the tests I use another implementation:

```
struct DummyLogger {
    tx: Mutex<Sender<String>>,
}

impl DummyLogger {
    pub fn new() -> (DummyLogger, Receiver<String>) {
        let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
        let logger = DummyLogger { tx: Mutex::new(tx) };
        (logger, rx)
    }
}

impl Logger for DummyLogger {
    fn log(&mut self, log_name: &str, data: &str) {
        let tx = self.tx.lock().unwrap();
        tx.send(data.to_owned());
    }
}
```

Which allows me to verify that it was both called the correct number of times, with the correct parameters:

```
let actual: Vec<String> = rx.iter().collect();
assert_eq!(actual, vec!["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
```